# Can you have more than one domready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm a bit new to mootools, but I know in jQuery you can have more that one function (in more than one file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

but can you do something similar with mootools?

I already have a `window.addEvent( "domready", function() {` already in my page and I really don't want to have to change that piece of code at all, but I want to be able to add another domready function in a seperate  file in the header.

Is this possible? Or am I just going to have to go about it in another way?

Comment: I don't know mootools, but the name of the method is a dead giveaway : `addEvent()` *adds* an event handler, so it probably can be called several times with different handlers. It would be named something like `setEvent()` otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you just test it and see if both pieces of code are executed?

Comment: Because they didn't seem to both running.

Comment: @Piers when you say they didnt' seem to both run do u mean run in parallel?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "firing"

Comment: @Piers when you say "firing" do you mean running in parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple `window.addEvent('domready', function(){});` but it kind of defeats Mootools' purpose of writting elegant code, in my opinion.

[Example w/ 3 Domready](http://jsfiddle.net/KPYFS/)

Comment: sometimes, you need to as you may have different sources - one domready callback may be an external js, 1 can be inline js from a pre-processor generated page (php etc)... not elegant but it works. :) +1 for you, sir!